# How can I filter consul nodes using multiple tags in consul-template?

Tags: nginx, consul, go-templates

I have a number of consul nodes that look something similar to:

```
 [
    {
        "Address": "127.0.0.1",
        "Node": "foo",
        "ServiceAddress": "",
        "ServiceName": "api",
        "ServicePort": 8100,
        "ServiceTags": [
            "production",
            "blocking"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Address": "127.0.0.1",
        "Node": "foo",
        "ServiceAddress": "",
        "ServiceName": "api",
        "ServicePort": 8101,
        "ServiceTags": [
            "production",
            "nonblocking"
        ]
    }
]
```

Filtering by one tag is easy:

```
{{range service "production.api"}}
{{.Address}}
{{end}}
```

but how can I filter services within my consul-template by two tags at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of consul-template v0.11.1 you can use the `contains` operator to do:

```
{{range service "production.api"}}
{{if .Tags | contains "nonblocking"}}
{{.Address}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

If you are using an older version you can take advantage of Go:

```
{{range service "api"}}
{{if and (.Tags.Contains "nonblocking") (.Tags.Contains "production")}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

see also: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/issues/260

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am using service tags in haproxy so similar could be done in nginx

```
{{ range $tag, $services := service "some-service" | byTag }}
backend some-service-{{ $tag }}

   {{ if eq $tag "some_tag" }}
   ....
   {{ end }}
   ...

   {{ range $services }}
   server {{.Address}}-{{.Port}} {{.Address}}:{{.Port}} check downinter 3s inter 2000 fall 3 maxconn 100 check cookie {{.ID}} weight 1
   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```